# SQL Update Reporting

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I need to record a the updates made in a Oracle MySql environment, using the front end. This acts as an Update query in the back end and overwrites the data in the database.

What is the best approach for this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. The question is unclear and too broad.

Comment: You can turn on query logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you track the user and can identify when the change comes from the front end then I would suggest using a trigger.